# How can I filter a jsonb field by multiple keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have groups that have a jsonb field - targets
my sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups.* 
FROM groups 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1 AND (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(targets) as a 
    WHERE a->>'name' ~* 'gender|age'
  ) 
)
```

this will return groups that contain only gender or only age, or both gender and age together.

How to fix it so that it returns only groups that have **both** **gender** **and** **age**

my jsonb field targets looks like this

```
[{"name"=>"gender", "value"=>"0"}, {"name"=>"age", "value"=>"1"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix it so that it returns only groups that have both gender and
> age

You can achieve this by using the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses, ensuring the presence of both elements by employing the `count()` function and the case clause :

```
SELECT user_id, targets
FROM groups
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(targets) as a 
GROUP BY user_id, targets
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN a->>'name' = 'gender' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND COUNT( CASE WHEN a->>'name' = 'age' THEN 1 END) = 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/l6RJ2qQX)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonb_path_exists`. See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.17.1.1.1).

```sql
SELECT
  g.*
FROM groups g
WHERE g.user_id = 1
  AND jsonb_path_exists(g.targets, '$[*].name = "gender"')
  AND jsonb_path_exists(g.targets, '$[*].name = "age"');
```